# protoc-jar-maven-plugin and protoc import path

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

I am currently working on an application composed of multiple Java services that should communicate using gRPC. The team decided to organize all .proto file in a central shared repository dedicated to that purpose.

The repository is structured as bellow :

```
.
├── service-a
│   └── v1
|       |── pom.xml
│       └── a.proto
├── service-b
│   └── v1
|       |── pom.xml
│       └── b.proto
```

To handle the code generation, we wrote a small bash script that loop over all services in the shared repository and generates, for each major version, a `pom.xml` containing a plugin to generate the Java classes and package them in a JAR with all required dependencies (i.e. `protobuf-java`, `grpc-protobuf`, `grpc-stub`).

A service's .proto files might reference messages from other services using imports. Yet I cannot figure a way to configure the `protoc-jar-maven-plugin` to tell `protoc` to set the import path to the shared repository's root so it can resolve the imports defined in each service's .proto files (all the import path in proto files are relative to the repository's root).

Bellow is an example of a .proto file importing another file and the configuration of the `protoc-jar-maven-plugin` inside the pom.xml generated for each service's major version directory:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package b.v1;

// Import statement allowing to use the "a.v1.A" message
// Path is relative to the shared repository's root
import "service-a/v1/a.proto";

service B {
  rpc someRpc(a.v1.A) returns (a.v1.A);
}
```

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
    <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>
                                <!-- Including all .proto file in the shared repo. so -->
                                <!-- that imports can be resolved -->
                <includeDirectories>
                    <include>../../</include>
                </includeDirectories>
                                <!-- Path to the service's .proto files -->
                <inputDirectories>
                    <include>./</include>
                </inputDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I try to generate the sources of a service that uses another service's messages, the plugin fails telling me that protoc exited with an error due to not finding the import defined in the service's proto file.

I should also specify that this POM sits at the same level as the .proto files for each major API version and is executed using `mvn clean install` so that the generated sources are installed on the local Maven repository for further local use.

So my question is, how can the plugin be configured to set protoc import path to the repository's root so that each .proto file imports are resolved ?

I tried tuning the `includeDirectories` and `inputDirectories` as specified in the [documentation](https://os72.github.io/protoc-jar-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) but without much success.

Comment: I don't use `protoc-jar-maven-plugin` but I am familiar with `protoc` and it's very particular approach to `proto_path` imports. Using `protoc` directly, `proto_path`'s must be absolute (unsure whether `../../` is permitted) **and** once a `proto_path` is specified, **every** subsequent `proto` referenced must use one of the `proto_path`'s. It's unclear to me but I'd encourage you to have a single root `proto_path` as the root of your shared repo (you may need others for external dependenceis) **and** then ensure that, for `b.v1.B`, you reference its proto against that root.

Comment: It may help you to use `protoc` directly to determine the configuration that you'd need for your folder structure and then convert that into the `protoc-jar-maven-plugin` format.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with that config which is similar to yours (except include directories) and works fine here?

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <protocVersion>3.11.4</protocVersion>
                                <includeDirectories>
                                    <include>src/main/resources</include>
                                </includeDirectories>
                                <inputDirectories>
                                    <include>src/main/resources</include>
                                </inputDirectories>
                               <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```